# resonance frequency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency, resonance, string, harmonics

A string has a mass per unit length of 9 10–3 kg/m. What must be the tension in the string if its second harmonic has the same frequency as the second resonance mode of a 2m long pipe open at one end? The length of the string is 1.5 m.

this is my solution

http://screensnapr.com/e/u4kvtH.png

i just want to ask if my second resonance mode understanding is correct.

Comment: What specifically do you suspect you might be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the calculation without first looking at yours (to make sure I wasn't influenced by any mistakes you might have made!) and got the same result, which is reassuring as I first learned this physics 35 years ago :-).

This is obviously a homework problem. I wonder if the point your professor is trying to make is that the first overtone of the string is double the frequency of the fundamental, but the first overtone of a closed pipe is three times the frequency of the fundamental.

Comment: tnx bro. 35 years wow

Comment: You'll be that old one day, and if I'm not dead I'll laugh :-)